# Is there an EXCEL function to choose the closest points below a certain line?

Tags: excel

Suppose that we have a scattered series of data X,Y randomly spaced (in the pic they are ordered, but this doesn't matter) and a line which shows the maximum limit we are considering for a sub-application.
[image: Problem]

Is there a combination of functions to choose the closest points below the orange line? I've tried with a MAXIFS + LOOKUP, but didn't solve anything.

Comment: You should start with determining the equation of the line y'=ax'+b. Then define the distance from the line (e.g. d=y-y' where y is the actual value of the point and y' is calculated from x with the above formula), then throw away positive values, and find the maximum with MAX (there may be more maximums, you did not indicate what should happen in that case), and then use MATCH to get its index.

Comment: How many points do you want? Just the closest, or say, the 5 closest? Suggest doing what @z32a7ul says to get an equation for the line (LINEST will help if you are trying to estimate the equation). Make a 3rd column in the POINTS table, and calculate the vertical distance of each point from the line: if the distance > 0 set it equal to -999 or something very negative. Then use the SORT array function to order the data from highest to lowest distance.

Comment: Is the 'x' reference for the line and the points will always be the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The formula of your line is: `y=1.17*x`, so you create a helper column, containing a formula like:

```
=IF(1.17*A3-B3>0;1.17*A3-B3;100000)
```

This means: calculate the difference between the line and the point if that difference is positive. In case it's negative (which means that the point is above the line), then show a value which is that large that it won't be taken into account while calculating the minimum.

You drag this formula all over the column.

You calculate the minimum of that column (one of the easy ways to do this, is using the autofilter).